# calling php functions from javascript, onload (AJAX?)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, function, onload

I have been searching for almost an hour without finding proper example to fix my problem:
I would like to call a PHP function (it's a simple unlink with the path given from a javascript function that's executed on page load). I am not good at all with AJAX and I would like to understand how to call directly the PHP function, contained in the index.php file, from the javascript code.

Here's what I have in my javascript code snippet:

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","/dev/templates/absolu/index.php?s=" + Math.random(),true);
//@unlink(listeImages[i].toString());
```

Comment: Take a look at performing an asynchronous HTTP request using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: The [xajax project](http://www.xajaxproject.org/) allows you to define functions in php then call them using javascript. I think it's just what you need.

Comment: All answers seem to be focused on `GET` but I would recommend switching to `POST` for a delete action.

Comment: `POST` won't bring anything more to this case..

Comment: Basically once PHP finishes building the page and sends it off to the browser, its work is done.  You can't "call a PHP function" from a browser.  What you can do is use AJAX to have the web-server process a new page request.  During this request you can execute some code on the server, call your function, etc., then send back any sort of message.

Comment: @skafandri Until your browser decides to speed up browsing by pre-loading some pages :-) I admit there is a bit more to it than just switching to `POST` but it is a good start...

Comment: @jeroen I never recommend an ORM when someone asks *how to connect to a mysql database* :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You send the function name (in case you will have more functions in the future) and params as get params

```
var fileToDelete;
var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/dev/templates/absolu/index.php?s=" + Math.random()+"&action=delete&file="+fileToDelete,true);
```

On your PHP script, you should handle it:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['action'])){
  switch($_GET['action']){  
     case 'delete':
       @unlink(listeImages[$_GET['action']].toString());
     break;
     //Other functions you may call
  }
  exit;
}
//The rest of your index.php code
?>
```

Comment: Actually, I would never write code like this one (I always use jQuery) but I just answered to the question :)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the help provided. Although, won't the website become more vulnerable do file deletion (as stated here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11208983/1451422 ) ? Other than that, this is exactly what I need!
Edit: A "POST" could do the job?

Comment: I gave you a **working** solution, you should wrap that code into a session control...

Answer (score 3):

You can't call directly a php function from an ajax call, it will only call the php script like if you were opening the page index.php from a browser.

You have to add tests in your php script to know which function has to be called, eg. :

If you call in ajax the page /dev/templates/absolu/index.php?mode=delete_image&image=filename.png

```
<?php
if($_GET['mode'] == "delete_image") {
    unlink($_GET['image']);
}
?>
```

Please take care that anybody could call this page so you have to check what will be deleted and to verify what you receive in GET parameters. Here i could call `/dev/templates/absolu/index.php?mode=delete_image&image=index.php` to delete the php script page.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery (http://jquery.com/) you could make the call as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("/dev/templates/absolu/index.php?", {
    'action': 'delete',
    'other': 'get-parameters',
    'r': Math.random()
  });
});
```

Server side example:

```
<?php

switch( $_GET['action'] ) {
  case 'delete': 
    // call unlink here
  break;
  case 'dosomething':
    // else
  break;
  default: 
    // Invalid request
  break;
}
```

Please note that deleting files should be handled responsibly (enforce security checks) to make sure no wrong file gets accidentally or on purpose deleted.

Comment: yeah I was gonna suggest that too... but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but let's say I want to call a specific function contained inside the index.php file, and not all of its code. (If I understood your snippet the right way)

Comment: @Ghillied You can use $_GET parameters to explicitly define the action you wish to invoke. I will update the answer to give you an example

Comment: So OP should start using a library to be able to use this?

Comment: @PeeHaa Well it's *the* library :) No if you are asking me if he has to, no he can use XMLHttpRequest, but I wish jQuery was there when I started doing AJAX requests :)

Comment: @PeeHaa Valid point, but the OP did state he's not good at all with ajax, so using a library might not be a bad idea. Not worse than copy-pasting code you don't understand any way at least...

Comment: I would just like to state I completely understand the code I use from human resources here, but I am asking since I am not familiar with jQuery nor AJAX functions, methods and variables. I did not know how to do this, but I can assure you I understood what I read ! ;)

Comment: IMO it's the other way around. You should only start thinking about using a library when you know what you are doing. This is not only about the library jQuery or the language javascript btw.

Comment: @PeeHaa In general I would agree with you, I wonder however if that can stand for a language such as javascript.

Comment: How is JavaScript different from c++ ? Do you learn to use QT before you know how to make a "hello world" ?

Comment: @tereško How exactly do you compare the two? Having to learn all quirks in JS between all available browsers is the same as learning QT before writing a "hello world"?

Comment: @mobius , well .. QT is a framework for (mostly) C++, just like jQuery is a framework for JavaScript and DOM. What exactly is so confusing to you? **You do no use framework, before you have learned the language!!**.